# ios: fit cell with label in it to the size of the label

Tags: ios, uitableview, size, label, cell

I'm having a `tableview` and loading data width a json Array.
What I'm doing is, I make two `UILabel` which i put in each table view cell.
This is working and with`[label sizeToFit];`.
My problem is now to set the size of the cell which is holding those two labels. I tried to set `[cell sizeToFit];`
but this isn't working.
Does anyone could help me to solve this?
Here is the code:

```
NSString * titel = [[json_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"maintitel"];
NSString * datum = [[json_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"datum"];

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:datum];

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.mm.yy"];
NSString * dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSString * datum1 = [dateStr description];

UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 50)];
label.text = datum1;

UILabel *label1 =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(80, 0, 245, 50)];
label1.text = titel;

label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

label1.numberOfLines = 0;
label1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

[label sizeToFit];
[label1 sizeToFit];

[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
```

My second question is because I'm almost new in iOS Developing but have already done some android projects, Is this the best way to make a screen looking like I want?

Comment: can use custom cell .To do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

NSString * datum = [[json_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"datum"];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [datum sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 77.0f);

    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

Consider a string wich is having max height then fit height for the cell .I considered datum string you implement according to your requirement

Comment: Hey thanks this is partly working when i set MAX(size.height, 50). But I don't know what the second value in the MAX means?

Answer (score 0):

I got it from my colleague (ANIRUDH) and working fine, may be helpful:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//Calculating height on base of length of text
    UIFont *font =  [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:YOURSTRING //[NSString string withformat:@"\n Yourstring"] \n for: number of lines require for static label in cell
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: font
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;

    //  NSString *height = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", ceilf(size.height)+22];
    return (ceilf(size.height)+22)*0.6; //change 0.6 to 0.9 according to the difference in required and extra calculted height, it works for me every time
}
```

and in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
.....
   label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.text = YOURTEXT;
     [label sizeToFit];

....

}
```

**BUT i recommend to go with http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/**